# The 3 graviton species

Tags: quantum-gravity, effective-field-theory

Recently, there is some speculation about the fact that quantum gravity could imply the existence (naturally, even without extra dimensions or any other stuff) of 3 gravitons: a massive spin-2 ghost and a massive graviscalar field.

[Gravitational Effective Action at Second Order in Curvature and Gravitational Waves](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5589814/), [DOI](https://dx.doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-017-5172-3), [arXiv:1708.08253](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08253)
[3gravitonspecies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5589814/)

1st. Why does the massive spin-2 GHOST make sense? Is it not cumbersome a PHYSICAL ghost with spin-2?

2nd. The additional massive scalar field, is correct to call it a graviscalar?

Comment: "Massive" $\neq$ "physical."